# Extend TypeScript 2.5.2 Component Props definition in a separate definition file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0, react-bootstrap-table

I have downloaded a NPM package called `react-bootstrap-table` with type definitions.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-table

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-bootstrap-table

Unfortunately the types are outdated and a prop called `strictSearch` is missing from `BootstrapTable` definitions that I need. I can of course update the definitions in `node_modules` but we are a team working on this project and we are not committing the `node_modules` folder.

I have read the thread here but I can't get it working anyway:

[How do I extend a TypeScript class definition in a separate definition file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217334/how-do-i-extend-a-typescript-class-definition-in-a-separate-definition-file)

How can I get it working?

If I add a new folder called for example "react-bootstrap-table-ex" everything looks good but of course I have no corresponding module for that.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap-table-ex'

If I rename my folder to `react-bootstrap-table` the types are only loaded from my new `index.d.ts` file and I cant reference the original definitions. I then tried to set the path for the original definitions manually but again the `Module not found` error occurs.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules/@types/react-bootstrap-table'
```

Code:

```
import { ComponentClass, Props } from "react";
import { BootstrapTableProps, BootstrapTable } from '../../node_modules/@types/react-bootstrap-table';

export interface BootstrapTableExProps extends BootstrapTableProps {
    strictSearch?: boolean;
}

export interface BootstrapTableEx extends ComponentClass<BootstrapTableExProps> {

}

declare const BootstrapTableEx: BootstrapTableEx;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Module Augmentation` to extend existing typings. Create .ts file with the following code

```
import { BootstrapTableProps, BootstrapTable } from 'react-bootstrap-table';

declare module "react-bootstrap-table" {
  export interface BootstrapTableExProps extends BootstrapTableProps {
    strictSearch?: boolean;
  }

  export interface BootstrapTableEx extends ComponentClass<BootstrapTableExProps> {

  }
}
```

New typings will be available in the entire project.

You can find more info here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html under Module Augmentation section.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Thanks to @niba I solved it like this, file `Typings\react-bootstrap-table-ex\index.d.ts`

```
import { BootstrapTable } from 'react-bootstrap-table';

declare module "react-bootstrap-table" {
    export interface BootstrapTableProps {
        strictSearch?: boolean;
    }
}
```

**Original:**

Solved it by copying `index.d.ts` from `node_modules\@types\react-bootstrap-table` into `Typings\react-bootstrap-table` and edit the file there.

My tsconfig.json below for reference:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //baseUrl and paths needed for custom typings
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [ "./Typings/*" ]
    },
    //We use webpack bundle instead
    "outDir": "./Scripts/NotUsed",

    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    //"experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [ "es5", "es6", "dom" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```