# Typescript Leaflet marker Custom property

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, leaflet.markercluster

I want to add a custom property to every marker, when I try the solution below I get this error:

> Property 'myCustomID' does not exist on type '(latlng: LatLngExpressio
>   n, options?: MarkerOptions) => Marker'.

```
let customMarker = L.marker([item.latitude, item.longitude], {
  //  customId:"010000006148",
  icon: icon({
    iconSize: [ 30, 41 ],
    iconAnchor: [ 13, 41 ],
    iconUrl: 'assets/icons8-street-view-64.png',
    shadowUrl: 'leaflet/marker-shadow.png'
  })
})

customMarker.myCustomID = "010000006148";
```

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217334/how-do-i-extend-a-typescript-class-definition-in-a-separate-definition-file

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
private addMarker(occurrence: Occurrence) {
        const options = {icon: this.icon};
        options['situation'] = occurrence.situation.value;
        this.mapOptions.layers.push(marker([occurrence.latitude, occurrence.longitude], options)
            .bindPopup(() => this.getPopupElement(occurrence)));
    }
```

Try to put your custom property in the options object of marker like this: 
`options['customProperty'] = customValue`;