# How to Augment an existing DefinitelyTyped definition for Chart.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js, definitelytyped

What is the proper way to add a static method to the Chart class?  This is a scaleService method that includes a function to update ScaleDefaults.

Here's the DefinitelyTyped definition:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chart.js/index.d.ts

I've tested by modifying the type in `node_modules` and it's working great, and I'm now trying to figure out how to [augment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) the type itself.

I've tried adding a folder in `src/customTypes` where I added a file called `chartjs.d.ts`.  Then I tried:

```
declare module "chart.js" {
  interface Chart {
    scaleService: {
      updateScaleDefaults: (type: ScaleType, updates: ChartScales) => void;
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything.  Here's the method from the docs that I'm adding.

[image]

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with chart.js typescript, but I'll try to help. Seems like the types file [declares `Chart` as class](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ee044bd8faafa661fcf89b37b697c0a8d220cbc9/types/chart.js/index.d.ts#L35) are you sure it should be an interface? You can get a clue by going to definition of `Chart` and see where it leads to.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes - it initially declares a class, then a namespace with the same name and exports them at the bottom of the index.d.ts file.  I need to add a static method to that class - and I have it working when I modify the node_modules d.ts file directly, but I'm not trying to remove those changes and augment in my code (so I can push and build).

Comment: Got you. Maybe the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23217334/863110) question can help. Don't forget to open a PR to the project with the updated API. Meantime, maybe you can fork it, modify and consume it using https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509764/863110

Comment: I finally got it!  Only took me 3 days.‍♂️ So what I did was I copied the entire d.ts file into a local directory in my /src, then I declared the chart.js module and wrapped all the code inside.  I then removed the @types definition from my packages.  The trick here was making sure that I `export as namespace Chart` inside the `declare module` because Chart.js uses the global namespace to import functions.

But this doesn't really answer my question.  I didn't want to completely remove the package, just update with some methods.