# can't get declaration in *.d.ts file to extend Express.Request

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, types, request

I'm trying to extend `Express.Request` with a user property (a TypeOrm Entity).

if i put the declaration in app.ts (main file) it's working:

```
import { User } from "./database/entities/user.entity";
  declare global {
    namespace Express {
      interface Request {
        user?: User;
    }
  }
}
```

but then i try to move it to `src/global.d.ts` file and it's not working anymore.

my `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "target": "ES6", 
    "module": "NodeNext",                                
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext", 
    "rootDir": "./src",                                 
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "removeComments": true,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

what am i missing here? tnx in advance

Comment: Have you seen this question? Perhaps the syntax in the answers will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58526827/237955